# OkHttp authenticator refresh token looping

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I have this piece of code in OkHttp Authenticator to refresh token when 401 response is returned from server, but as soon as 401 is returned this code starts looping without end each time with new access and refresh tokens, any idea what could be wrong?

````
override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
    val refreshToken = tokenManager.getRefreshTokenFromSharedPrefs()

    val refreshTokenRequest = NetworkRefreshTokenRequest(refreshToken!!)

    val tokenResponse = authApi.api.refreshToken(refreshTokenRequest).execute()

    return when(tokenResponse.isSuccessful){
        true -> {
            val tokens = tokenResponse.body()!!

            Timber.tag("AUTHENTICATOR TOKEN: ").i(tokens.token)
            Timber.tag("AUTHENTICATOR R_TOKEN: ").i(tokens.refreshToken)

            tokenManager.saveTokensToSharedPrefs(tokens.token, tokens.refreshToken)
            response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", "Bearer ${tokens.token}").build()
        }
        else -> null
    }

}```
````